# GreenCard: What restrictions on priority date retention?

Tags: immigration

- I received my H1b (not H1b1) visa stamp in early 2017. My Singapore passport expires in Sep 2019, and my H1b visa expires at the same time.
- I first used it to enter U.S. in Apr 2017. Now I’m in the early stages of GC. I hope to get my PERM approved in mid-2018, under my current employer P. Once I get my priority date, I plan to relocate to Singapore for 2 to 3 years, where I will get a new passport. I will need a new visa stamp -- is it hard? I assume it’s not hard in Singapore.
- When I re-enter U.S. to work, perhaps 2021, on the new H1b visa stamp, I will probably work for the same employer P, or possibly a different employer. Will I keep my priority date? Friends tell me to beware of risks and complications. Are there?

Comment: Do you plan to go to Singapore because you believe it to be a necessary step in the process or for other reasons?

Comment: Answer is the latter. Personal/family reasons.